Перерисовка окна при перемещении: Кривая винда и костыль
Моей специфической задачей является рисование картинки рабочего стола прямо на моей форме, таким образом, чтобы они полностью совпадали. (пожалуйста, не спрашивайте зачем).
TL;DR: SSCCE ниже. Картинка криво рисуется при перемещении окна.
unit Unit1;

interface

 uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Graphics, Forms, PNGImage, Jpeg;

 type
  TForm1=class(TForm)
   procedure FormCreate(Sender:TObject);
   procedure FormShow(Sender:TObject);
   procedure FormPaint(Sender:TObject);
   procedure FormDestroy(Sender:TObject);
   procedure WndProc(var Mssg:TMessage); override;
  end;

 var
  Form1:TForm1;
   isFormDoneCreated:Boolean;
  BmDesktop:TBitmap;

implementation {$R *.dfm}

function LoadGetBmDesktop:TBitmap;
  var
   png:TPngImage;
   jpg:TJpegImage;
   txt:String;
 begin
  txt:=GetEnvironmentVariable('USERPROFILE')+'\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\TranscodedWallpaper';
  Result:=TBitmap.Create;
  try
   Result.LoadFromFile(txt);
  except
   png:=TPngImage.Create;
   try
    png.LoadFromFile(txt);
    Result.Assign(png);
   except
    jpg:=TJpegImage.Create;
    try
     jpg.LoadFromFile(txt);
     Result.Assign(jpg);
    except
     FreeAndNil(Result);
    end;
    FreeAndNil(jpg);
   end;
   FreeAndNil(png);
  end;
 end;

procedure Draw;
 begin
  var num:=(Form1.Width-Form1.ClientWidth) div 2;
  Form1.Canvas.Draw(-Form1.Left-num, -Form1.Top-(Form1.Height-Form1.ClientHeight)+num, BmDesktop);
 end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender:TObject);
 begin
  BmDesktop:=LoadGetBmDesktop;
 end;
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender:TObject);
 begin
  isFormDoneCreated:=True;
 end;
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender:TObject);
 begin
  Draw;
 end;
procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender:TObject);
 begin
  FreeAndNil(BmDesktop);
 end;

procedure TForm1.WndProc(var Mssg:TMessage);
 begin
  case Mssg.Msg of
   WM_MOVE:
    if isFormDoneCreated then
     Draw;
  end;
  inherited;
 end;

end.

Пример выше предполагает, что способ рисования обоев установлено на "Замощение".
Если окно оказывается в другом месте на экране, то и отображать оно должно тоже другую часть картинки рабочего стола.
Проблемы начинаются во время перемещения этого самого окна, а именно: изображение начинает "плавать" и "рябить" -- (по ощущениям) каждый второй кадр рисования позиция изображения становится некорректной, из-за чего оно отображается со смещением относительно обоев. Величина неправильного смещения прямо пропорциональна от скорости перемещения окна.
При этом такая проблема отсутствует при изменении размеров окна с любой стороны и с любой скоростью.
Этот странный баг портит всю эстетику моей задумки. Когда форма стоит -- всё прекрасно; когда форма resize'тся -- всё прекрасно; но когда форма перемещается -- хочется плакать.
Для меня это более разочаровывающее, чем для большинства, ведь я любуюсь на эту "красоту" при своих 280 fps.
Я бы продемонстрировал проблему визуально, но очень сложно ужать гифку до 2 мб; так что пожалуйста, запустите пример самостоятельно, чтобы прочувствовать всю эту прелесть.
Вот демонстрация факта наличия смещения в замедленной сьёмке:

Много месяцев подряд я не знал что с этим делать; пришлось во время перемещения окна отображать всё чёрным цветом. И вот недавно, когда я в очередной раз безнадёжно скитался по просторам stackoverflow'а, копируя себе весь код, который попадётся мне под руку, в надежде, что что-то сработает, мне внезапно повезло нажонглировать себе случайным образом костыль, который неожиданно сработал:
...

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender:TObject);
 begin
  FreeAndNil(BmDesktop);
 end;

var omgCrutch:Boolean;
procedure TForm1.WndProc(var Mssg:TMessage);
 var irec:PRect;
 begin
  case Mssg.Msg of
   WM_MOVE:
    if isFormDoneCreated then
     Draw;
   WM_MOVING:
    begin
     irec:=PRect(Mssg.LParam);
     irec.Bottom:=irec.Bottom+(Ord(omgCrutch)*2-1);
     omgCrutch:=not omgCrutch;
     DefWindowProc(Form1.Handle, Mssg.Msg, Mssg.WParam, Mssg.LParam);
    end;
  end;
  inherited;
 end;

end.

Каким-то образом DefWindowProc() с изменением Rect'а в LParam полностью нивелирует эту плавающую рябь! Независимо от скорости перемещения окна, всё рисуется ровно; её как рукой сняло. Счастья полные штаны.
Но как это работает... я конечно же, в ахрене. Настолько чёрной магии я ещё в жизни не видел. (возможно мне даже будут сниться ночные кошмары).
(upd) DefWindowProc() не обязателен, без него костыль тоже отлично работает.
Моё программистское чутьё подсказывает мне, что это костыль тот ещё жуткий. Адекватное решение вообще существует? Как рисовать картинку "ровно", без танцев с бубнами и шаманскими тотемами?
Изменения размера окна в процессе перетаскивания по одному пикселю, конечно же, не заметно, но всё равно кринжово.
А если этот костыль и есть часть адекватного решения, то тогда как сделать так, чтобы изменения +1 -1 Rect'а не было, а баг при этом всё равно исчез?
Потому что если оставить код как есть, только без изменения на один пиксель, то всё снова становится плохо.
(upd) Маленькая заметка для истории: У меня ещё была идея для костыля, которая заключалась в имитации перемещения окна с помощью увеличения его размера с одной стороны, и уменьшения с другой. Коли resize работает так гладко, можно было бы переписать поведение перемещения в терминах resize'а. Однако такой костыль -- очень огромные и сложные дебри, я не потянул бы.

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.
